# Solve for variable, to calculate GAP from speed and grade

Tags: math, algebra

```
(speed * 0.2) + 3.5 = ((gap * 0.2) + 3.5) + (gap * grade * 1.8)
```

Trying to rearrange this to solve for GAP, given that speed and grade are known.  My algebra is struggling.  Anyone have any suggestions on how to rearrange this equation?

EDIT:
Trying to rearrange to be used as formula for calculating GAP (grade adjusted pace) based on Speed and Grade while parsing GPS data.

Based on the below accepted solution:
$gap = $speed / (1 + (9 * $grade))

Comment: This belongs on math.stackexchange.com, I think.

Comment: try distributing your multiplications to your coefficients   (0.2speed) + 3.5 = 0.2gap + 3.5 + (1.8gap * 1.8grade)

Comment: You can go to http://math.stackexchange.com/ for math problems, or try it out at [WolframAlpha](http://wolfr.am/1dzwN8b).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(speed * 0.2) + 3.5 = ((gap * 0.2) + 3.5) + (gap * grade * 1.8)`

Subtract out the 3.5 from both sides.

```
(speed * 0.2) = (gap * 0.2) + (gap * grade * 1.8)
```

Multiply both sides by 5 (purely visual).

```
speed = gap + (gap * grade * 9)
```

Factor out gap on the RHS.

```
speed = gap * (1 + (grade * 9))
```

Divide both sides by the grade factor.

```
gap = speed / (1 + (9 * grade))
```

Comment: Can you explain the "Factor out gap on the RHS" line? What's happening there?

Comment: The right hand side has two things that involve the gap variable. We need gap to be on it's own in order to put the equation in the desired form. Effectively we're dividing just the RHS by gap and then bracketing the result and multiplying by gap again. I'm sure there's a name for this technique but high school was a while ago :)

Answer (score 0):

```
gap = 0.2*speed / (0.2 + 1.8*grade)
```

Comment: Can you show maybe 2 of the main steps to get it there so the solution is understood?